# C# Socket does not send complete data

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to create a client/server application where a server sends commands to clients and clients send result back. The clients send data like this:

```
5|Hello
```

5 is the length of the string which is sent because then the server knows howmany characters it should receive before it should do something with that data. I tried to do that with this code:

```
 private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer).Contains("|"))
                {
                }
                string[] a = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer).Split('|');
                while (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer).Length < (Int32.Parse(a[0]) + a[0].Length + 1))
                {
                }
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                    int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
                    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
                    Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
                    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
                    if (!text.Contains("GET") && !text.Contains("HTTP") && text != null)
                    {
                        
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ":" + text);
                    }
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

but this still does not give me the correct result. Also the CPU goes very high.
Picture of the result:
[image: Result]

Can someone explain me why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Recieve method returns count of bytes recieved. Use it instead of your prefix.

Comment: Just looping in an endless loop hoping for someone to fill your buffer isn't going to work. You need to keep reading until you get enough data, not just spinning on the CPU. And you keep overwriting your buffer rather than adding to it. At the same time, you expect it to not contain anything dangerous, like a `|` from some previous message. There's just too many problems with your code. Networking is hard :)

Comment: @Seprum It returns the count of bytes read into the buffer. That isn't enough to know when the message ends, as Jesse has already noticed - some form of message framing is necessary if you have a persistent connection.

Comment: @Luaan Then he needs to make some counter and apply count of recieved bytes to it as well as apply new portion of bytes to some list of bytes. When the counter reaches prefix value, the cycle should stop.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Seprum and Luaan. I understand what you are saying but I dont know how to code it. If you have the time I would appreciate if you could give me a little example in code.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `Encoding.ASCII`to `Encoding.UTF8`.

It can fix you issue.

Do note that you must to use the same encoding on both sides (sending and receiving data).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  But that did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using TcpClient? it can be way easier and gives you more control.

something like;

```
//make connection
NetworkStream stream = null;
socket = new TcpClient();
socket.Connect("192.168.12.12", 15879);
if (socket.Connected) {
    stream = socket.GetStream();
}

//and than wait for tcp packets.
connectionThread = new Thread(ListenServer);
connectionThread.Start();

private void ListenToServer() {
    Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
    String message = String.Empty;
    Int32 dataLength = 0;
    while (socket.Connected) {
    try {
        while (stream.DataAvailable) {
            dataLength = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, dataLength);
            //do what ever you need here
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

moreover %1 cpu load!